# BLE: How to find exactly my device between scan results?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm a newbie on Android BLE programming.
So, I need a people who have a professional skills on a BLE concept :)

I made a app which connect between apple device and android phone.
apple device is slave, so apple send advertise message to android periodically. 
But I have a little confused how to find my bluetooth device between scan results.

```
m_lescanner.startScan(filters, new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(2).build(), m_scan_callback);
```

My app enroll broadcast receiver to listen bluetooth events.
If the events occurs, app start scanStart function to gathering BLE device near by android phone.

```
    private ScanCallback m_scan_callback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
```

After that, I got a many BLE device results including my BLE device(apple device) But I don't know what BLE results is mine....

**all MAC address is different, and all UUID is null(I'm also confused why this flags is different and results is null).**

Thank you for reading my question. 
PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: What is the Apple device advertising?

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://github.com/GitGarage/BLEMingleDroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/bitgarage/blemingledroid/ScanActivity.java

Comment: @Christopher Thank you for my reply. Apple device advertising packet is message what scanning results after startScan function on android.

Comment: @vookimedlo Thank you vookimedlo. This link is helpful for me but I have a problem. I found that BLE device what already paired isn't searched on scanResult class. Then how to I resolve this? Thank you again.

Comment: There could be several possibilities why this could happen. I would start with the following test. Try to search for the BLE device from the different phone. It might be possible that the BLE device has inquiry scan disabled once paired with other device, but the page scan has enabled. This means, it's only connectable, but cannot be no longer searched. Based on the result (if BLE device is visible from other phone), I would tend to use this nice Android BLE library hiding all platform changes: https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-Scanner-Compat-Library